# SQL Server / C# connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2014 on my Windows Server 2012 r2 machine, and put my database file on it. How make a connection string to allow access to the database?

I used this connection string

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

when i run the query i get login failed

Comment: have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: have u tried putting "localhost" instead of your IP and port like Data Source=localhost;

Comment: Doesn't work? what error do you get? Is your database file MDF? Did you `sp_attach` it?

Comment: when i run the query i get login failed

Comment: Have you tested that the login / pwd is correct through SQL Server management studio?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Network Library and create `SqlConnection` Object:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server=90.190.200.100,1433;database=myDatabase;uid=myUsername; pwd=myPassword
```

Comment: One-line answers, while likely correct, don't help the questioner understand the problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

Data Source=90.190.200.100,1433;Initial Catalog= <--DB Name-->;User ID=<--UserID-->;Password=<--Password-->;

Answer (score -1):

did you added your port 1433 under Firewall configuration (Inbound rules)?

Whenever you're trying to access database using IP address, it will come through the firewall so must configure Port under firewall to enable connection.

Comment: yes i did 
what else configuration do i need on sql server

Comment: can you tell me where did you added firewall configuration for the port ?
Or try to connect using Sql Server Management Studio using Server authentication method with IP and Port number. see what is the error it is giving?
Also check again port number is it mapped one ?  1433 is default port

Comment: Now that you have told us you get a 'login failed' error, we know it's not a firewall or connection issue

Comment: It may be issue with services also, check the services running or not?